# RPM Sometimes Jumps

Tags: rpm, acceleration, cv-joint, peugeot-207

I have noticed an issue today when driving and was hoping someone might have some ideas. Car is a 2008 PEUGEOT 207.

I have noticed that sometimes when I floor the accelerator at 4th and 5th gear, the RPM will shoot up to 3-4 rather than the usual 1-2 but the speed will not increase in tandem. This does not always happen and seems to be random. If I bring the accelerator back up and then gradually increase the speed, it tends to be fine.

From what I've seen online, a lot seems to indicate as to a slipping clutch or something. Would I notice any other symptoms if this was the case? The clutch feels normal and there is no grinding noise, nor no odd smell which I've seen people say are also symptoms of a slipping clutch.

I know I have a leaking CV Boot (leaking grease into the passenger side wheel). It's due to go into my mechanic this week - could this be the cause of my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Try and set off with the parking brake pull on. If the car stalls or spins the wheels (front wheel drive) all is normal. If the car remains stationary and the engine remains running (for a short while) the clutch is slipping. If the car drives away, the parking brake is shot

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the problem is the clutch and it's slipping quite severely. This is a classic symptom of this problem, with or without the smell associated with it. When a clutch is fully engaged, it should be a very linear RPM to speed movement, meaning, as the RPMs go up, so should the speed. If the RPMs shoot up and the speed doesn't, something is slipping. This could either be the tires roasting on the pavement or the clutch not gripping as its supposed to. Since you didn't mention doing donuts, I'm betting on the slipping clutch.

The CV joint would have nothing to do with this. If the CVJ quit working, your car wouldn't move.

Comment: Thanks. Thankfully my mechanic is a family friend, so will get him to have a look at it this week when I stop by his! Hoping it's nothing that will be too expensive to fix. Sorry for my ignorance but would it be a 'clutch kit' used to repair the clutch? Just had a Google and to know what sort of price range I'm in for to fix it - the kits seem a lot less expensive than I was expecting!

Comment: @Jordan - Yes, a clutch kit would be correct. It can include the pressure plate, friction disk, throwout bearing, and the pilot bushing. You can also get them with the flywheel. Of note, though, is that the clutch kit is probably the cheap part of this ... it's the labor which will get you because the transmission has to be separated from the engine in order to make the repair. This might "just" be removing the tranny, but I would bet in your Peugeot it's going to mean removing the engine and tranny, separating them, install the new clutch, then back in. It's a chunk of time to get it done.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought it would be an engine out job, maybe a transmission out though

Comment: @CaiusJard - It's a front wheel drive vehicle. Since this comes as a unit, the engine/transmission usually have to come out together to get them separated. This isn't a hard and fast rule, but the vast majority of FWD vehicles are this way.

Comment: Happy to bow to your experience but I'd have definitely expected "engine out" to be the exception rather than the norm for a clutch change ...

Comment: @CaiusJard - Look at it this way, something has to come out. On FWD vehicles, the engine, for the most part, is attached to the transmission (on most, two of three "motor" mounts come off of the transmission). There isn't room enough to remove the engine off of the transmission input shaft, so they have to come out together. Once out, it's fairly easy to get them separated and the clutch assy changed out. I was able to get the engine out of the '03 Civic I used to own, however, the service manual (and everyone online) said you have to remove them as a unit. I enjoyed proving them wrong. :o)